# What is the meaning of "it'll do that to you"?

Tags: meaning

I read this  in a dialogue.

> **She**: You’re no fun anymore since you got shot.
>     **He**: I hear it’ll do that to you.

What is the meaning of "it'll do that to you"? Could you please help me? I have no idea.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, deli! I have edited your comment into your question. As in all languages, utterances mean different things in different contexts, so we usually need the specific context you're asking about; and you're more likely to get answers if you include the context in your question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, "I hear it'll do that to you" is a phrase that indicates, sarcastically, that the other person is not being empathetic or considerate enough. You can replace it with something like "that's only natural considering the circumstances", but while such a reply would be fairly neutral, "I hear it'll do that to you" indicates that the speaker is annoyed.

"I hear" is supposed to indicate tones of sarcasm, invoking an unspoken "knowledge" which is supposed to show that the end result should be a matter of common sense. After that, "it'll do that to you" just indicates that the end result (*"that"*, that the man in the conversation is no longer fun) is intrinsically linked to the previous action (*"it"*, that the man in the conversation was shot).

Answer (score 1):

> I hear it’ll do that to you.

Let's break the sentence down. It = getting shot; that = make you no fun. So it becomes:

> I hear **getting shot** will **make you no fun**.

Most cases I've heard this said, it's an attempt at humor.